# I am getting ERROR: AttributeError at /customer/5/ type object 'Customer' has no attribute 'orderitem_set'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Please help me I stuck at this problem. When Click on the **view** button I want to show all the orders from that user as shown in the image below, but when i click on it I am getting this error instead of order details for that customer.

[image]

The models file contains

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer)

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in orderitems:
            if i.product.digital == False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total    

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total
```

The views.py file contains
**Views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@admin_only
def customer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = Customer.orderitem_set.all()
    shippinginfo = customer.shippingaddress_set.all()

    total_order = orders.count()

    context = {'customer': customer, 'orders': orders, 'total_order':total_order, 'shippinginfo': shippinginfo}
    return render(request, 'store/customer.html', context)
```

[image]

Comment: `orders = customer.order_set.all()` (with lowercase `c`).

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code where you instantiate orderitem_set. You only reference it

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated it but now it is only showing the 5 rows as there are 5 orders of the user. But the product name and quantity are not displaying because in the order model it does not exist.  So what can I do instead of using 'order_set.all()'

Comment: @AndyKnight I am using it from the OrderItem model.

Comment: @AndyKnight I am able to access ```order_set()``` but not ```orderitem_set.all()```

Comment: @Jain could you please the full code snippet for reference?

Comment: @TusammaSalSabil  here is the full code ... https://github.com/Bhavik-Jain/project_ecomm/tree/main/ecommerce

Comment: @Jain, I try to reproduce the issue but couldn't able to do that. everything seems working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Do it like :-

```
def customer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.orderitem_set.all()
    shippinginfo = customer.shippingaddress_set.all()

    total_order = orders.count()
```

**What i have changed ?**

I have related (connected) `orderitem_set` with the existing `id` with `existing query`.

**EDIT :-**

I have found the problem in your [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Bhavik-Jain/project_ecomm/blob/main/ecommerce/store/views.py#L128).
The Problem is in the `updateItem` view.

You're saving the order but you're not relating the `request.user` as a `customer` with the order.

So do it like :-

```
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productID = data['productID']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action:', action)
    print('productID:', productID)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productID)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

# Add this line
    orderItem.customer = request.user.customer
    orderItem.save()


    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

Comment: It worked but when a customer makes a new order then the ```Customer``` field does not update automatically.  I have added a new image above please check it for reference.

Comment: So, you mean it is not relating `customer` with order . If that is the problem then - Can you show the view which is saving the order form (Order Items) ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the **views** in question

Comment: @BhavikJain, Check the Edited Answer

Answer (score 1):

Add a related_name field in your models.py on Order model like

```
class Order(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(
    Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="orders")
```

And then in views.py

```
def customer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.orders.all()
```